# Passing ifstream as parameter in functions

Tags: c++, function, file, parameter-passing, ifstream

I'm trying to make a the contents. However, I'm having quite a bit of trouble with ifstreamI'm probably lacking knowledge as I'm quite new to coding, but I'd appreciate any help

Comment: Where in your code have you attempted passing an ifstream as a parameter? What errors, exactly, do you get?

Comment: If I tried to pass the ifstream through the function, the file variable wouldn't work as it wasn't the same type.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the attempt you made that you're having trouble with and the exact error. I don't know which of several functions you've written is "the function", or how you tried to pass the ifstream to it as a parameter.

Comment: If I change the "string f" to "string & f", down in main the string I input into the function no longer works.

Comment: What does "no longer works" mean? Fails to compile? Compiles but produces unexpected output? And in either case, what does that have to do with attempting to pass an `ifstream` as a parameter?

Comment: That's because `"A:\\Coding\\Hobbit.txt"` isn't a `string`. It's a [string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal), an array of constant `char`s. It can be converted to a `string`, but it expires so fast that it's useless to you. The compiler protects you from bad code by rejecting it. If you ` const string & f` the compiler will perform some deep magic and keep it alive for you

Comment: streams cannot be passed by value because that would make a copy of the stream. Think of what could happen if you have multiple copies of `cin` floating around. one copy could read a few characters of input, then another `cin` could read a few more and no body would get the whole message. Total chaos. You can pass a stream by reference or you can `move` it.

Comment: user4581301 - thanks for the help, apologies if I was unclear.

Comment: The best way to be clear is to provide the code that doesn't work (preferably as a [mre]) and the exact text of the error message with the question. Less noise in the question almost always gives faster and better results. Even better, making the [mre] often leads you to the solution.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't really clear what you're asking here.

With regards to passing an instance of `std::ifstream` as an argument, it may be because you aren't using references correctly.

Notice the reference operator (`&`) next to the `file_stream` argument. This will prevent the errors I expect you're seeing, that might look like this without it:

> use of deleted function ‘std::basic_ifstream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_ifstream(const std::basic_ifstream<_CharT, _Traits>&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits]’
> file_reader.printFile(file_reader.file_stream);

This error is happening because you're trying to copy the stream instance. Passing-by-reference means the function will use the *same* instance of the stream, not a copy of it.

Here's an example of what your program might look like. I've used your approach of handing the class its own members to operate on (in this case, `file_stream`), but this *is* an odd way of doing it. Perhaps read up a little more on how classes work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

class FileRead {

public:

    std::ifstream file_stream;

    FileRead(const std::string &file_name) {
        file_stream = std::ifstream(file_name);
    }

    static void printFile(std::ifstream &file_stream) {
        std::string word;
        while(file_stream >> word)
            std::cout << word << std::endl;
    }

};

int main() {
    FileRead file_read("A:\\Coding\\Hobbit.txt");
    file_read.printFile(file_read.file_stream);
}
```